# TLS + NodeJS, how it is possible to get client's public key bytes on server side

Tags: node.js, ssl, cryptography

I have a TLS server and a client, client connects to server using a handshake during which they both exchange their public keys and after that settle a passphrase which is later used by AES encryption to speed things up, my question:

Is there a way to obtain client's public key that is used during handshake procedure?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found out the answer, just google for "nodejs getPeerCertificate", here's complete walkthrough:

https://gist.github.com/sandfox/1831932